# How do I know what to name a file downloaded using HTTP?

Tags: sockets, http

I am creating an HTTP client downloader in Python. I am able to correctly download a file such as http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png just fine. However, I'm not sure what to actually *name* the thing.

There is of course the filename at the end of the URL, but is this always reliable?

Comment: You can leave as is, or randomize, or use timestamp. The real question is what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So you're saying it's pretty much up to my discretion?

Comment: If there's a Content-disposition header with a filename component, use that, otherwise it's up to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly, wget uses the following heuristic:

1. If a `Content-Disposition` header exists, get the filename from there.
2. If the filename component of the URL exists (e.g. `http://myserver/filename`), use that.
3. If there is no filename component (e.g. `http://www.google.com`), derive the filename from the `Content-Type` header (such as `index.html` for `text/html`)
4. In all cases, if this filename is already present in the directory use a numerical suffix, such as `index (1).html`, or overwrite, depending on configuration.

There are plenty of other flags that control other heuristics, such as creating .html for ASP/DHTML content-types.

In short, it really depends how far you want to go. For most people, doing the first two + basic Content-Type->name mapping should be enough.